# Return value from gRPC Interceptor in F# without knowing return type

Tags: generics, f#, grpc, interceptor

I am trying to implement a `Grpc.Core.Interceptors.Interceptor` in F#. Simplified, my interceptor method takes a `UnaryServerMethod<'request, 'response>` and returns a `'response`. I know what I want to return when `'response` is a particular type. But I don't know how to return it within the F# type system when the return type is generic.

Here is my current code:

```ml
type ExceptionInterceptor() =
  inherit Grpc.Core.Interceptors.Interceptor()
  with
    override _.UnaryServerHandler(request, context, continuation: UnaryServerMethod<'request, 'response>) =
      task {
        try
          return! continuation.Invoke(request, context)
        with e ->
          return
            if typeof<'response> = typeof<MyResponse> then
              // Compiler error:
              // The 'if' expression needs to have type ''a' to satisfy context type requirements. 
              // It currently has type 'MyResponse'.
              generateFromException e // returns type MyResponse
            else
              raise e
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is going to be possible within the F#/.NET type system. The problem is that your `if` test happens at run-time, but code generation is done at compile-time. You and I know that the `true` branch will only be taken when `'response` is `MyResponse`, but the compiler still has to generate code for that branch that works for *all* types, not just `MyResponse`. That means that `generateFromException` has to be generic for the code to compile.